# escaping comma for faker on lumen seeder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen, faker

I'm learning to do some simple migration and seeding on lumen using factory and faker to mysql database, below are my codes :

`PostSeeder.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostSeeder extends Seeder
{
    
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\Post::class, 40)->create();
    }
}
```

and on the factory `PostFactory.php`

```
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'post_id' => Str::uuid(),
        'title' => $faker->sentence(3),
        'content' => $faker->realText(200),
        'user_id' => Str::uuid(),
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 years', 'now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'created_by' => Str::uuid(),
        'app' => NULL
    ];
});
```

when I tried to run the seeder got error like this :

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for
> column 'user_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into 'posts' ('post_id', 'title',
> 'content', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'created_by', 'app') values
> (c1460ae8-e472-4439-aad8-af3aaf090268, Assumenda
> ipsa corrupti., King triumphantly, pointing to the shore, and then
> treading on her spectacles, and began picking them up again as quickly
> as she could. The next thing was snorting like a wild beast,
> screamed 'Off.))

I'm not sure, but looks like on faker realText comma is not being escaped on the query, is there anything I need to add on the factory to escape the faker, or need to do something on the database?

I'm using mysql 14.14 on ubuntu 18.04 and lumen 7.x
on posts table the content type is text

Comment: check the size of 'user_id' it should have at leaats 36

Comment: As nbk said, check the length of column `user_id`, based on the `Data too long for column 'user_id' ` portion of the error message. Has nothing to do with comma's from the `realText`.

Comment: thanks, looks like I'm not checking well enough, after checking on table, the issue are the size of user_id column